# How do I solve chamber 6, chapter 8 properly?

Tags: portal-2

Yesterday I kludged my way around chamber 6 in The Itch. What I did:

1. Obtain a cube, blocking it from emancipation with the wall
2. Extend bridge ahead of turrets
3. Once 'safely' through the emancipation grid keep a portal on the back side of the chamber
4. Portal the cube on the other side of the room
5. Now I can't setup the antiturret bridge again, so via trial and death I try and launch the cube as far as I can without being mowed down.
6. Eventually I manage to push the cube on the button, not on the side with legs, and back out in the nick of time
7. I move along

This must be suboptimal, and the... supervisor points out that surely there must be a better way. It then agrees there isn't, but in context that means very little.

Is there a better way, or is GLaDOS that sadistic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's what I did for the chamber it sounds like you're describing:

1. Obtain a cube

   - Place a hard light wall over the turret pit so when you call for a cube it's not immediately emancipated
     [image]
   - Hit the button and go catch it (or if you're really lucky, it will bounce back enough to stay up)
     [image]
2. Go up near the exit with the cube

   - Use the light wall to prevent overshooting the catwalk
     [image]
3. Once there, place a portal to block off the turrets

   - this is before walking around to the ledge above the button
     [image]
4. Go put the cube on the button
   [image]
5. Portal out, using the one you blocked the turrets with (orange in above picture would go on the surface to the left on this side of the emancipation field)
6. Go back up to the exit

If you get it down (or don't mind getting more cubes), you can just throw the cube off the ledge onto the button and skip 3-6 entirely.

Comment: This is the same way I solved it and I heard the "suboptimal" message as well - I just assumed it was a part of the script

Comment: Recurring theme in Portal: AIs are annoying, condescending, and psychopathic.  Not sure why everyone keeps thinking that they turn over a new leaf for an instant.

Comment: In Step 5 you can just use the two portal surfaces on the side to go "upstairs" directly :)

Comment: Note that if the cube goes into the pit in step 1b, you can just portal down to get it.

Answer (score 2):

You can still use the anti-turret bridge, only this time further from the turrets on the other side of the emancipation grid. You should be able to see the bridge source from your vantage point.

Comment: I see the bridge source, but not the other side of the bridge it hits the wall on, where I should place the portal to extend it...